# Add ORDER BY clause in VB.Net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How to concatenate

```sql
ORDER BY
```

clause in VB.NET?

Here's what I've tried:

```vb
Using command As New SqlCommand()
    command.Connection = conn

    Dim parameterNames As New List(Of String)(dt_data.RowCount - 2)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt_data.RowCount - 3
        Dim parameterName As String = "@meter_num_" & i
        Dim meter_number As String = dt_data.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, meter_number)
        parameterNames.Add(parameterName)
    Next

    command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cycle = @cycle and meter_num IN ({0})", String.Join(",", parameterNames), ("ORDER BY Client_Name ASC"))
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cycle", cycle2last)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "customer")
    Compare_Reading.dt_last2month.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
End Using
```

I wanted it to be like this

```sql
Select * from table_name 
where column_name = @column and column2 = @column2 
ORDER BY column_name ASC
```

Comment: Just add to the end of the string `String.Format("Select ... and meter_num IN ({0}) ORDER BY Client_Name ASC", String.Join(",", parameterNames))`

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Wouldn't that be open to SQL injection since you're not using parameters at all?

Comment: You use parameters for cycle but then you just munge together a bunch of other strings values and execute it. This code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange what is the proper way to avoid sql injection?

Comment: In this case I would use a table valued parameter. That would be much simpler. I am guessing that dt_data is a DataTable? You could just pass the DataTable as your table valued parameter and then use an inner join in your query.

Comment: yes dt_data is a DataTable

Answer (score 0):

To do that in a single instruction you need to replace

```
Compare_Reading.dt_last2month.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

With:

```
Compare_Reading.dt_last2month.DataSource = (From existing As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Select Order By existing.Item("your_filed_name_to_order_here") Ascending).CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: In SQL string the better technique is as @Fabio explain before.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about List(Of T) is that you don't need to know the size before adding items. It will expand as necessary. So, I deleted the int32 from the constructor.

I think you want `dt_data.RowCount -2` in `For` loop or you will skip the last row. I changed your `.AddWithValue` to `.Add`. You will have to check your database for the correct datatypes (I guessed) and adjust the code accordingly.

I think your main problem was in `String.Format`. You added the 2 parameters but neglected to put in the `{1}`.

I added a `Debug.Print` so you can check that your Select looks like you expect. This will appear in the immediate window when you run in debug. It won't effect the release version.

You don't need a `DataAdapter` or `DataSet` just a `DataTable`. Assign the `.DataSource` outside of the `Using` block.

I don't think there is any concern about sql injection because you have properly used parameters for all the variables.

```
Private Sub OPCode(cycle2last As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using command As New SqlCommand()
            command.Connection = conn

            Dim parameterNames As New List(Of String)
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
                Dim parameterName As String = "@meter_num_" & i
                Dim meter_number As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
                command.Parameters.Add(parameterName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = meter_number
                parameterNames.Add(parameterName)
            Next

            command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cycle = @cycle and meter_num IN ({0}) {1}", String.Join(",", parameterNames), ("ORDER BY Client_Name ASC;"))
            command.Parameters.Add("@cycle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cycle2last

            Debug.Print(command.CommandText)
            conn.Open()
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```